# How to build a simple web page Monitor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, server, monitoring

I would like to write a javascript program to monitor a given web page (like a shopify page) and create an alert when a change is detected.

What is the simplest way to implement this in Javascript? Is there any one library that provides tools to monitor page changes? Ideally, this program could run continuously on my computer and create a notification on my phone.

For the phone notification part, I was thinking I could just use [a whatsapp Bot](https://www.callmebot.com/)  to send a text to my phone

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, if so what?

Comment: I know this is Python, not JS, but [here's a script](https://github.com/Wunders/website-change-telegram/blob/master/website-change-telegram.py) that does exactly what you need (no point re-inventing the wheel). Or if you need something with a GUI and more options, there's also [changedetection.io](https://github.com/dgtlmoon/changedetection.io) (self-hosted). For more info, see [awesome-website-change-monitoring](https://github.com/edgi-govdata-archiving/awesome-website-change-monitoring)

Comment: Thanks @Lissy93 ! this is exactly what I was looking for. I assumed there must be some pre-existing scripts out there but was having a tough time sifting through expensive software on Google